# Warnings for functions without type specs?

Tags: types, erlang, compiler-warnings

I want all of my exported functions to have type `-spec`s, to ensure that there is at least basic documentation of the interface. Can I make the compiler or Dialyzer emit warnings for functions without type specifications?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an undocumented compiler (not Dialyzer) option called `warn_missing_spec` that does this.  On the command line, pass `+warn_missing_spec` to `erlc`:

```
erlc -o ebin +warn_missing_spec foo.erl
```

If you use Rebar, add `warn_missing_spec` to `erl_opts`:

```
{erl_opts, [warn_missing_spec]}.
```